# python opencv detect the image is completely white

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

How to detect if an image is white. It means that the image has only a white background.
This is for black background.
Example code:

```
image = cv2.imread("image.jpg", 0)
if cv2.countNonZero(image) == 0:
    print "Image is black"
    return True
else:
    print "Colored image"
    return False
```

Comment: check if all pixels has r,g,b=255,255,255 or #FFFFFF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform a bitwise_not operation on the input image and apply the same logic(this is just a hack):

```
image = cv2.imread("image.jpg", 0)
image = cv2.bitwise_not(image)

if cv2.countNonZero(image) == 0:
    print "Image is white"
    return True
else:
    print "Black region is there"
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use [numpy.all](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html):

**Full white image:**

```
img_white = np.ones([10, 10, 3], np.uint8) * 255

res1 = np.all([img_white == 255])
print(res1) #=> True
```

**Non full white image:**

```
img_non_white = img_white.copy()
img_non_white[1, 1] = (100, 255, 255)

res2 = np.all([img_non_white == 255])
print(res2) #=> False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the image with OpenCV, then it comes as a numpy array. So what you need to do is to check how many white points are in there.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('img.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
n._white_pix = np.sum(img == 255)
```